# Sencha touch basic concepts and webservers

Tags: mobile, web-applications, sencha-touch, webserver

Hey guys been doing a lot of research mostly because I've been wanting to get into application development in my free time. I was able to figure out how to install everything properly and get it to generate the generic application with the loading page which I thought was cool and was able to run it with ripple emulator.

My questions are as follow:

1. The web server, what's the point of running it and having it? I can run the sencha web start command and it starts a web server at localhost 1841 but I can't type anything in the command prompt and I don't know what it's for mostly. What uses does it have for building an app? And what does Sencha's differ from other ones?
2. Running sencha -cw , a command so that I can change the directory for whatever reason gives me a missing required argument error at com.sencha.cli.Arguements.mustPull etc. Will that have an effect on me later when I am developing my app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

download xampp and install it.

and start the xampp Apache Module.

Place your SenchaToch app in htdocs folder.

and now goto localhost/yourappname.

it's enough for sencha app.